# Laravel validate array iterations

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, laravel, validation

I sent an array from my form by javascript which gets values from different input fields and then storing it in a single variable.

```
<input type="hidden" name="details" id="details">
```

js

```
document.querySelectorAll('form')[1].addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
    var details = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < {{ $event->grocery->items()->count() }}; i++) {
        details[i] = [
            document.querySelectorAll('.store')[i].value,
            document.querySelectorAll('.item')[i].value,
            document.querySelectorAll('.quantity')[i].value,
            document.querySelectorAll('.brand')[i].value,
            document.querySelectorAll('.size')[i].value,
        ];
    }

    document.querySelector('#details').value = JSON.stringify(details);
});
```

Then in my controller, I decode the array using `json_decode`

```
$request->details = json_decode($request->details);
```

Now, I want to validate each iteration (just to check whether it is empty or not). So, I do like this,

```
$request->validate([
    ...
    'details.*.*' => 'required'
]);
```

But my problem is that this is not doing anything. Even if I sent an empty iteration it continues without returning an error.

Am I doing anything wrong here? Please help me.

**Update**

Example var dumping details

```
array:3 [▼
  0 => array:5 [▼
    0 => "Grocery"
    1 => "Grocery"
    2 => "Grocery"
    3 => "Grocery"
    4 => "Grocery"
  ]
  1 => array:5 [▼
    0 => "Grocery"
    1 => "Grocery"
    2 => "Grocery"
    3 => "Grocery"
    4 => "Grocery"
  ]
  2 => array:5 [▼
    0 => "Grocery"
    1 => "Grocery"
    2 => "Grocery"
    3 => "Grocery"
    4 => "Grocery"
  ]
]
```

Comment: you do not specify **which** fields should be present for each array item. E.g.  `'details.*.*.store'`

Comment: @ThomasMoors Even if I do `'details.*.0'`, it doesn't care.

Comment: is `0` a field? No `'details.*.0'.quantity'` could be required. That the field `quantity` should be present on every 0th item inside an array inside an array called details...

Comment: @ThomasMoors, I don't think so. If you take a look at the js code you can see that I am creating an associative array.

Comment: Can you show us what `var_dump(json_decode($request->details))` displays?

Comment: @Troyer Updated my question

Comment: @Troyer That's why I used `*` to validate all the iterations

Comment: @Troyer I am validating `$request->details`. That's how it's done in Laravel

Answer (score 1):

It would make it easier if you named your array values

```
document.querySelectorAll('form')[1].addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
    var details = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < {{ $event->grocery->items()->count() }}; i++) {
        details[i] = {
            store: document.querySelectorAll('.store')[i].value,
            item: document.querySelectorAll('.item')[i].value,
            quantity: document.querySelectorAll('.quantity')[i].value,
            brand:document.querySelectorAll('.brand')[i].value,
            size: document.querySelectorAll('.size')[i].value,
        };
    }

    document.querySelector('#details').value = JSON.stringify(details);
});
```

The validation would look like this:

```
$request->validate([
    ...
    'details.*.store' => 'required',
    'details.*.item' => 'required',
    'details.*.quantity' => 'required',
    'details.*.brand' => 'required',
    'details.*.size' => 'required'
]);
```

But if it doesn't suit you there is always Laravel's [Custom Validation Rules](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#custom-validation-rules)

**EDIT**:

I think maybe the issue is with the update of your data:

```
$request->details = json_decode($request->details);
```

Instead you should [modify your input befor validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35246487/laravel-5-1-modify-input-before-form-request-validation/42527938#42527938) and [Modify input before form request validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31850622/modify-input-before-validation-on-laravel-5-1)

```
$request->request->set('details', json_decode($request->details));
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response. But, still it's not working

Comment: I think it is an object rather than an array. Can you show me how to validate an object?

Comment: Convert it to [associative array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) with `json_decode($request->details, true);`